# Will the linux "shutdown" command allow a parameter to determine the pause between sending SIGTERM and SIGKILL?

Tags: linux, shutdown, delay

The man page seems to indicate no.  There is /etc/rc.d/init.d/halt on Fedora. It has a hard coded pause in it, but there's got to be a better way than to change that script.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

The manpage on my system has:

```
-t sec Tell  init(8)  to  wait sec seconds between sending
processes the warning and  the kill signal, before changing 
to another runlevel.
```

(This is probably a more appropriate question for serverfault)

Comment: Is this what wants the OP? A delay between the *warning* and the actual *shutdown*? Or a delay between *SIGTERM* (ask gracefully the processes to terminate) and *SIGKILL* (kill processes immediately)?

Comment: Have you tried it?  That seems to be deprecated. I certainly can't get it to work on any distribution I've tried.

Comment: @ring0: the SIGTERM is the warning.

Comment: @s2cuts:  I have. I'm running a reasonably current debian with the sysvinit package (2.88dfs).  The "upstart" init replacement does indeed ignore this option.

Comment: The SIGTERM is *not* a warning! `shutdown` sends first a warning text message saying that `the host is going down in x minutes`, *then* it issues a SIGTERM, and *then* after a couple of seconds X, it issues  the fatal SIGKILL. The OP, as far I understand his needs, wants to control the *X* value. This is not what would do the *deprecated* `-t` option.

Comment: @ring0: I admit the man page is phrased badly.  There is a text warning that is sent immediately, but it's sent to logged in *users*, not processes.  Then it waits until the shutdown time to send both SIGTERM and SIGKILL, waiting the time given by the -t argument.  In context, the warning referred to really does mean the warning signal of SIGTERM -- the only warning processes can receive is signals.

Answer (score 0):

In order to have a specific delay between SIGTERM and SIGKILL, you could specify three commands in a script as root

```
kill -SIGTERM -1
sleep 20
kill -SIGKILL -1
```

to

- send SIGTERM to all processes (but 1),
- wait for 20 seconds, then
- send the `-9` signal to kill immediately the remaining processes,

**but** it would kill your own processes, your `shell` interpreter... 
Developing a script (e.g. in Perl) to list all processes, then to kill only the processes that do not harm your own script, and start it within `nohup` to attach it to the father-of-all `1` process, would do the job.

Another solution is to download the source of `shutdown` (or `halt`) and see how it works - adding a fixed or optional delay between the sending of the two signals shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: This is probably the closest to a solution.  I've already modified /etc/rc.d/init.d/halt and put a more suitable pause in between the sending of SIGTERM and SIGKILL.  The only problem is that it's hard coded.